# How to read manufacturer information from system (in detail serial number) from UWP

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I managed to get Productname and SKU so far with

```
    var clientDeviceInformation = new EasClientDeviceInformation();
    string Model = clientDeviceInformation.SystemProductName;
    string SKU = clientDeviceInformation.SystemSku;
```

but I cannot find any way to get the system serial number.
In W32-forms-application, we could get it via `System.Management` and `Win32_BIOS`, but that seems to be no way for UWP.

Anybody's got a hint for me?

Comment: `Windows.System.Profile.SystemManufacturers.SmbiosInformation.SerialNumber`?

Comment: that doesn't seem to work in an UWP
`System.UnauthorizedAccessException: "Access denied"`

Comment: You need [the `smbios` capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) to access the serial number.

Comment: As @RaymondChen says, you need the capability because this allows your app to track the device. You are unlikely to be able to publish in the Microsoft Store with this capability, but you could use it for a private LOB app etc. What do you need the serial number for?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I'm trying out some things for a registration process. Didn't think a serial number would be such critical information. Guess I need to add the app to device metadata. There seems to be no other way

Comment: HardwareIdentification may be sufficient for your needs. Not sure why you need the serial number for a registration process. Would an app-specific hardware id be sufficient? (Serial numbers are sensitive information because it lets you track the device across multiple apps. E.g. your app collects the serial number and gives it to an advertising network. Another app does the same thing. The advertising network can now correlate information between the two apps, which is much more powerful than what the apps could do by themselves.)

Comment: @RaymondChen, sorry for the late reply - been on vacation.
I totally understand your concerns now. The way of use you describe is indeed a tracking option. That's not what we want to do and I never even thought about it before. But it's understood now.